# Can isomorphic spectral sequences converge to non-isomorphic limits?

Tags: definition, examples-counterexamples, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

**Overview:** I'm learning about spectral sequences by working through exercises in Chapter 10 of Bourbaki's Algebra book. One of the exercises makes me suspect that the notion of *isomorphism of spectral sequences* is poorly behaved in general. **Bourbaki seems to think that you can have two spectral sequence which are isomorphic, but which converge to different limits.**

(This would be completely outrageous, which is why I'm confused! Hopefully I missed something simple.)

**The Problem:**
Problem 14c of Section 2 asks to show that an isomorphism $u:E\to E'$ of spectral sequences induces isomorphisms
$$
B(u_r): B_r \to B_r', \qquad
Z(u_r): Z_r \to Z_r', \qquad
u_\infty: E_\infty \to E_\infty',
$$
of the associated data;
for the last two isomorphisms, 
Bourbaki says we should assume that $E$ and $E'$ are *regular* (this is a finiteness condition; see the definitions below).
Is this assumption strictly necessary?
Shouldn't an isomorphism of spectral sequences trivially give isomorphisms of all associated data, including the limits, in all cases?

More concretely,

> Is there an isomorphism $u:E\to E'$ of spectral sequences $E$ and $E'$ whose induced map $u_\infty : E_\infty\to E'_\infty$ on the limits is *not* an isomorphism?

(Bourbaki seems to think there is.)

**Definitions:**
A spectral sequence $E=(E_r,d_r)$ comes with a natural filtration
$$
0 = B_0 \subseteq B_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq 
B_\infty := \bigcup_{r\geq0} B_r
\subseteq \bigcap_{r\geq0} Z_r =: Z_\infty \subseteq \cdots
Z_1 \subseteq Z_0 = E_0
$$
where $Z_r / B_r$ is isomorphic to $E_r$. We define
$$
E_\infty = Z_\infty / B_\infty.
$$

The spectral sequence $E$ is *regular* if for all $(p,q)$ the sequence $(Z_r^{pq})_{r\geq0}$ eventually stabilizes.

A *morphism* $u:E\to E'$ of spectral sequences $E$ and $E'$ is a sequence of chain maps $(u_r : E_r \to E_r')_{r\geq0}$ such that $u_{r+1}$ is the map on homology induced by $u_r$.

An *isomorphism* of spectral sequences is a morphism $u:E\to E'$ with an inverse $u':E'\to E$, or equivalently, a morphism $u:E\to E'$ such that for each $r$, the chain map $u_r$ is an isomorphism. (In fact, $u$ is an isomorphism if $u_2$ is.)
This definition of isomorphism is my own, not Bourbaki's, but it seems the only natural definition.

Comment: There are much better ways to learn about spectral sequences than just going through the few exercises in Bourbaki's book...

Comment: Thank you for your concern. How do you recommend I learn about spectral sequences?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22188/introductory-book-on-spectral-sequences is a good start. Bourbaki's book only contains a few exercises on spectral sequences, it's not really a textbook about them as far as I can tell...